# How can I avoid ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException or IndexOutOfBoundsException?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

If your question is *I am getting a `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` in my code and I do not understand why it is happening, what does it mean and how can I avoid it?*

> This is meant to be the most comprehensive [canonical](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291994/177800) collection of information on this
> `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` topic as well as the `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

There are many questions like this and all of them have either vague no-code answers, or mostly they are extremely specific and localized to the question at hand and do not address the root cause which is exactly the same in all cases.

---

> *If you see one that falls under this general case, rather than answer it with more duplicate specialized content, mark it as a duplicate of this one.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### What is java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException / java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException?

The [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html) curtly states:

> Thrown to indicate that an array has been accessed with an illegal
> index. The index is either negative or greater than or equal to the
> size of the array.

### What causes it to happen?

> This exception means that you have tried to access an index in an
> array or array backed list and that index does not exist.
>
> Java uses `0` based indexes. That means all indexes start with `0` as
> the index of the first element if it contains any elements.

The `IndexOutOfBoundsException` message is very explicit, and it usually takes the form of:

`java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1`

Where `Index` is the index that you requested that does not exist and `Size` is the length of the structure you were indexing into.

As you can see a `Size: 1` means the only valid index is `0` and you were asking for what was at index `1`.

> For example, if you have an raw `Array` of objects or primitive types
> the valid indexes are `0` to `.length - 1`, in the following example the valid indexes would be `0, 1, 2, 3,`.

```
final String days[] { "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday" }
System.out.println(days.length); // 3
System.out.println(days[0]); // Sunday
System.out.println(days[1]); // Monday
System.out.println(days[2]); // Tuesday
System.out.println(days[3]); // java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

This also applies to `ArrayList` as well as any other `Collection` classes that may be backed by an `Array` and allow direct access to the the index.

### How to avoid the `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` / `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException`?

#### When accessing directly by index:

> This uses [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) to convert the raw primitive `int[]` array to an
> [`ImmutableList<Integer>`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.html). Then it uses the `Iterables` class to safely
> get the value at a particular index and provides a default value when
> that index does not exist. Here I chose `-1` to indicate an invalid
> index value.

```
final List<Integer> toTen = ImmutableList.copyOf(Ints.asList(ints));
System.out.println(Iterables.get(toTen, 0, -1));
System.out.println(Iterables.get(toTen, 100, -1));
```

If you can't use Guava for some reason it is easy to roll your own function to do this same thing.

```
private static <T> T get(@Nonnull final Iterable<T> iterable, final int index, @Nonnull final T missing)
{
    if (index < 0) { return missing; }
    if (iterable instanceof List)
    {
        final List<T> l = List.class.cast(iterable);
        return l.size() <= index ? l.get(index) : missing;
    }
    else
    {
        final Iterator<T> iterator = iterable.iterator();
        for (int i = 0; iterator.hasNext(); i++)
        {
            final T o = iterator.next();
            if (i == index) { return o; }
        }
        return missing;
    }
}
```

#### When iterating:

> Here is the idiomatic ways to iterate over a raw `Array` if you need
> to know the index and the value:
>
> This is susceptible to *one off errors* which are the primary causes
> of an `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`:

##### Using a traditional *for*-*next* loop:

```
final int ints[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
for (int i = 0; i < ints.length; i++)
{
    System.out.format("index %d = %d", i, ints[i]);
}
```

#### Using an enhanced *for-each* loop:

> Here is the idiomatic way to iterate over a raw `Array` with the
> *enhanced for loop* if you do not need to know the actual index:

```
for (final int i : ints)
{
    System.out.format("%d", i);
    System.out.println();
}
```

### Using a type safe Iterator<T>:

> Here is the safe way to iterate over a raw `Array` with the *enhanced
> for loop* and track the current index and avoids the possibility of
> encountering an `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.
>
> This uses Guava to easily convert the `int[]` to something `Iterable`
> every project should include it.

```
final Iterator<Integer> it = Ints.asList(ints).iterator();
for (int i = 0; it.hasNext(); i++)
{
    System.out.format("index %d = %d", i, it.next());
}
```

If you can not use Guava or your `int[]` is huge you can roll your own `ImmutableIntArrayIterator` as such:

```
public class ImmutableIntArrayIterator implements Iterator<Integer>
{
    private final int[] ba;
    private int currentIndex;

    public ImmutableIntArrayIterator(@Nonnull final int[] ba)
    {
        this.ba = ba;
        if (this.ba.length > 0) { this.currentIndex = 0; }
        else { currentIndex = -1; }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() { return this.currentIndex >= 0 && this.currentIndex + 1 < this.ba.length; }

    @Override
    public Integer next()
    {
        this.currentIndex++;
        return this.ba[this.currentIndex];
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() { throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); }
}
```

And use the same code as you would with Guava.

If you absolutely **must have the ordinal** of the item the following is the safest way to do it.

```
// Assume 'los' is a list of Strings
final Iterator<String> it = los.iterator();
for (int i = 0; it.hasNext(); i++)
{
    System.out.format("index %d = %s", i, it.next());
}
```

This technique works for all *Iterables*. It is not an *index* parse, but it does give you the current position in the iteration even for things that do not have a native *index*.

#### The safest way:

> The best way is to always use [ImmutableLists](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.html)/[Set](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableSet.html)/[Maps](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html) from Guava as
> well:

```
final List<Integer> ili = ImmutableList.copyOf(Ints.asList(ints));
final Iterator<Integer> iit = ili.iterator();
for (int i = 0; iit.hasNext(); i++)
{
    System.out.format("index %d = %d", i, iit.next());
}
```

### Summary:

1. Using raw arrays are difficult to work with and should be avoided in most cases. They are susceptible to sometimes subtle [*one-off errors*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error) which have plague new programmers even back to the days of [BASIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BASIC)
2. Modern Java idioms use proper type safe *collections* and avoid using raw *array* structures if at all possible.
3. Immutable types are preferred in almost all cases now.
4. Guava is an indispensable toolkit for modern Java development.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the Java documentation for *[class ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html)*, this exception is thrown when you try to access an element that is either negative, or greater than the size of the array.

Consider the case you have 10 items in the array.  You can ask the system for the first to the tenth item within the array.  If you try to ask for the -1 item or the 100th item in the array, Java would respond with the above exception.

Now keep in mind that an array in Java is [zero-based](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_type#Index_origin).  Therefore, you can only pass an index value of 0 to 9 inclusive. Any number not in this range will throw the specific error mentioned above.

To avoid this exception, let's go back to the concept of computer science [101](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/101#Adjective), and review the concept of a [loop invariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_invariant).  This is a condition to make sure that the variable you use to store the index must meet a particular condition.