# Array exception ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I want to ask something because I don't understand something.
I want to found min element in array, when I use this code it is fine:

```
public static int najmanji(int[] niz) {
    int min = niz[0];
    for (int el = 0; el<niz.length; el++) {
        if (niz[el] < min) {
            niz[el] = min;
            return min;
        }
    }

    return min;

}
```

But when I use foreach loop I have exception `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

```
public static int najmanji(int[] niz) {
    int min = niz[0];
    for (int el : niz){
        if (niz[el] < min) {
            niz[el] = min;
            return min;
        }
    }

    return min;
 }
```

Why I have this error? Because `foreach` is same like `for` loop?

Comment: [How to avoid java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32568261/how-to-avoid-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception)

Comment: @Blue Master also your min function is not returning min. Example:int[] datas1 = {5,6,7,8,4,3,2,1}; najmanji(datas1) would return 5, which is clearly not the min. Use this: public static int najmanji2(int[] niz){
     int min=niz[0];
     for(int el=0;el<niz.length;el++){
         if(niz[el]<min){
             min = niz[el];  
         }
     }

     return min;

 }

Answer (score 2):

`el` does not represent an index; it's the actual value.

```
for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
    int curVal = myArray[i];
    //your code...
}
```

Is the same as

```
for (int curVal : myArray){
    //your code...
}
```