# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when running range query in Accumulo

Tags: java, accumulo, geomesa

I am using Geomesa 1.1 to connect to Accumulo 1.6.2 with Java. I have no problems querying the database for specific attributes (specific column values). But when I try to run a range query (tried both time and geometric ranges) I get an error.

When I check the Accumulo logs I see this error:

```
exception while doing multi-scan 
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
```

**But none of my code uses Arrays. The exception is thrown from the underlying library.**

This is how I am constructing my `CQL` filter:

```
Filter cqlFilter = CQL.toFilter("BBOX(where, 160.0, 1.0, 170.0, 3.0)");
```

What might be causing the `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1`?

EDIT

Updated question and answer to make it clear it isn't a duplicate and provide more general help to future visitors.

Comment: Don't suppose you have the full stack trace for that exception, do you?

Comment: I think I've figured out the problem. I'm pretty sure it was a dumb mistake on my part (as these things usually are). If I'm right I'll add the answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Geomesa/Accumulo will misleadingly throw this red herring error if you pass an invalid/incorrect table name to `toFilter`.** Before you spend a lot of time reading through [general solutions to this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32568261/how-to-avoid-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception) and searching your code for bugs, be sure that you have the correct table name.

Answer (score 0):

As a quick note, it looks like you might be using the GeoMesa Accumulo QuickStart.  The geometry field there is named 'Where'.  If you update the filter to

```
Filter cqlFilter = CQL.toFilter("BBOX(Where, 160.0, 1.0, 170.0, 3.0)");
```

it may work for you.