# Error: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 2, size is 2

Tags: java, android, listview

How to remove the seperator line in `footerLayout`? I have a `footerLayout` below the `listView`, used to display the totalAmount as shown below. If I click the seperator line in `footerLayout`, my app crashed.

[image]

**My MainActivity**

```
AllAdapter obj = new AllAdapter(getApplication(), search, listview,imageView,text,button);
footerLayout = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.under_listview, null);
totalAmount = (TextView) footerLayout.findViewById(R.id.amount);
```

**LogCat error**

```
 java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 2, size is 2
            at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
            at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
            at com.example.tony.monthlyexpenses.adapter.AllAdapter.getItem(AllAdapter.java:61)
            at com.example.tony.monthlyexpenses.QuickExpenses$1.onItemClick(QuickExpenses.java:88)
            at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:301)
```

The error pointed to `listView` `onClickListener`

```
 listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view, final int position, long id) {
                mClickedPosition = position;
                Expenses o = (Expenses) obj.getItem(position);
                String day = o.getDate();
            }
        });
```

**AllAdapter**

```
 public Expenses getItem(int position) {
        return search.get(position);
    }
```

The footerLayout is supposed to be displayed outside the listView, not inside. How can I get rid of this ?

I also have `activity_main.xml`, `AllAdapter` class, `all_adapter.xml` for `ListView` and also `under_listview.xml` for the `footerLayout`.

[activity_main](http://pastebin.com/CNGXC0rf)

[AllAdapter](http://pastebin.com/aXP8Wu4c)

[under_listview](http://pastebin.com/3J1u4tct)

> How to move the footerLayout out from the ListView ?

I add  `android:footerDividersEnabled="false"` now become like this

[image]

But still clickable !!!

[image]

Comment: please share the xml

Comment: @Swas_99 edited. I have 3 xml, one is activity_main, another is adapter, lastly is footer layout xml. Let me know which xml .

Comment: So is the issue, the footer is in the list view and the position is greater than the number of objects in obj? Maybe you should just add a check before you do getItem.

Comment: @matt How can I move the footerLayout out from listview ?

Comment: @matt this is java. sure we deal with 0 based indicies...

Comment: @Hoo Do you ave an custom litViewAdapter? If so, could you please provide your full listViewAdapter?

Comment: @malik The title of the question seems to imply op is not clear about that detail.

Comment: @matt post edited.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException or IndexOutOfBoundsException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32568261/how-to-avoid-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-or-indexoutofboundsexception)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The footerLayout is supposed to be displayed outside the listView, not
>   inside.

Actually, the footer is also part of the `ListView` and it adds up to the number of items the list has. Neverhteless, there are a few approaches how to ignore the click events on a footer view.

One option is instead of adding your view using:
`addFooterView(footerLayout);`,
use:
`addFooterView(footerLayout, null, false);`

The third parameter specifies whether the footer view [should be selectable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addFooterView(android.view.View,%20java.lang.Object,%20boolean)) or not.

Another option would be to ignore the click when the `position` parameter is bigger than the size of your adapter dataset:

```
 listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view, final int position, long id) {
          if(position < adapter.getCount()){ 
              Expenses expenses = (Expenses) adapter.getItem(position);
              String day = expenses.getDate();
          }
     }
 });
```

Comment: THANKS ! `addFooterView(footerLayout, null, false);` did the tricks.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the following line in your listview.

```
            android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
```

Comment: add it to your ListView in xml

Answer (score 1):

I change this code and it works fine now.

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view, final int position, long id) {
                Expenses o = (Expenses) listView.getAdapter().getItem(position);
                if(o != null){
                    mClickedPosition = position;
                    //Expenses o = (Expenses) obj.getItem(position);
                    String day = o.getDate();
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

just a quick tutorial, if you are new to custom ListViewAdapters.

I would have an Object `Expense` like this:

```
class Expense {

  Date date = new Date();
  Double spendMoney = 5.0;
  Bitmap image;
  ...

  /** Continue with POJO **/
}
```

and an `expenses_list_item.xml` layout. (if you need help with that, i can add it later...)

In my MainActivity I would have an `ArrayList<Expense> expensesList`
and 
my **custom** `ArrayListAdapter` would look something like this:

```
class expenseListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Expense> {

    expenseListAdapter() {
        super(context, R.layout.expenses_list_item, expensesList);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int pos, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (view == null) {
            view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item_series, parent, false);
        }

        ShowListItem current = expensesList.get(pos);

        TextView expens = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.expenseText);
        expens.setText(current.getSpendMoney());

        ... (all other needed values of your Expense object)

        return view;
    }
}
```

And finally, I could just set

```
ArrayAdapter<Expense> adapter = new expenseListAdapter();
expenseListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

That would be it. Maybe a little bit complicated on the first look, but this method is very powerfull. If you need help, don't be afraid to ask ;)

Greets
Malik

Comment: Thanks, Malik,I have all these. I will update my post

Comment: Edited. Please check