# ArrayList.clear throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, arraylist, concurrency

Getting below exception on `ArrayList.clear()`
Any reason why would clear throw such exception.  I know add or get might throw this for  negative index or larger thn list size.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=49; index=49
       at java.util.ArrayList.clear(ArrayList.java:569)
```

Comment: Could please share a piece of code that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Do you by any chance modify the list concurrently?

Comment: Length is 49, and index starts at 0, so the maximum index is 48. https://stackoverflow.com/a/32568266/4161471 https://stackoverflow.com/q/5554734/4161471

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)

Comment: @aSemy this question is specifically asking about `clear()` and mentioning the OP knows about indices issues, so it's not really a duplicate IMO (there is no useful answer there regarding this specific problem, which is most likely caused by concurrency issues)

Answer (score 5):

The implementation of `ArrayList` is not thread safe by [design](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). Specifically regarding `clear()`, the code assumes that the size of the list doesn't change while `clear` is executing.

Most likely, you have another thread that reduces the the list size concurrently with `clear` which causes the logic to try and access an index that is out of bounds.